# How to direct to a different url if check box enable

Tags: javascript, html

with some advice from this forum below code is working for me when I type in the textbox and it will direct to a url.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function test() {
  if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == 'google'){
    // alert('Input can not be left blank');

  window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
  }
  if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == 'yahoo'){
    // alert('Input can not be left blank');
  window.location.href = "https://www.yahoo.com/";
  }

 else if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == ''){
     alert('Input can not be left blank');

   }else if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() != ['google'||'yahoo']){
    alert("INVALID Entry");
  }
}
</script> 

<form id="main" name="main"><input type="text" name="inputtext" id="inputtext" placeholder="type here"/><input type="button" value="submit" onClick="test();"></form>
```

Is it possible to add a checkbox, and if checkbox is checked with text input it should direct to another url.

ex: now if I type google it directing google.com, Required if checked box is checked and if typed as google it should direct to gmail.com

form in below

```
<form id="main" name="main">
<input type="text" name="inputtext" id="inputtext" placeholder="type here"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="inputcheckbox" id="inputcheckbox">Redirect
<input maxlength="10" type="button" value="submit" onClick="test();" ></form>
```

Kindly advice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For jQuery  1.6+ :**
 You can use `$('#inputcheckbox').prop('checked'))` to check whether the checkbox is checked or not.

**for jQuery < 1.6 :** 
`$('#inputcheckbox').attr('checked'))`.

I am using `change` event to check the condition, so if you want to check your condition on submit click you can copy the code inside it to your submit event/function. 
Below is my sample code.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#inputtext,#inputcheckbox').change(function() {

    if ($('#inputtext').val() == 'google' &&
      $('#inputcheckbox').prop('checked')) {
      alert('redirecting to google...')
      window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main" name="main">
  <input type="text" name="inputtext" id="inputtext" placeholder="type here" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="inputcheckbox" id="inputcheckbox">

  <input maxlength="10" type="button" value="submit" onClick="AddPrinter();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your problem, but it seems you want to change the redirect URL to www.gmail.com when the user types "google" and checks the checkbox.

You can achieve this the following way:

```
if($('#inputtext').val() == 'google' && $('#inputcheckbox').isChecked) {
  window.location.href = "https://www.gmail.com/";
}
```

PS: You can use `$` instead of `jQuery` in your code, it has the same effect and keeps the code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

add checkboxes with different IDs

```
<input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected"/>
```

then use script

```
if(document.getElementById('isAgeSelected').checked) {
    window.location.href = // Some URL
}
```

another way is

```
$('#isAgeSelected').click(function() {
    window.location.href = // Some URL
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function test() {
  if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == 'google' && jQuery('#inputcheckbox').isChecked){
    // alert('Input can not be left blank');

  window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
  }
  if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == 'yahoo' && jQuery('#inputcheckbox').isChecked){
    // alert('Input can not be left blank');
  window.location.href = "https://www.yahoo.com/";
  }

 else if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() == ''){
     alert('Input can not be left blank');

   }else if(jQuery('#inputtext').val() != ['google'||'yahoo']){
    alert("INVALID Entry");
  }
}
</script>
```

I hope my answer will help you.